# Just doing my homework

Tags: enigmatic-puzzle, knowledge

> **Note: I only wish I had a teacher that gave me homework like this.**

My teacher gave me rather weird homework... what does it mean? I am doing it here.

```
5.11G, 2
5.6G, 2
6.13G, 1
2.16G, 1
3.15G, 1
6.11G, 2
4.12G, 1
5.4G, 1
6.13G, 2
4.4G, 2
7.12G, 2
4.13G, 1
```

Hint 1:

> G stands for something.

Edit/Hint 2:

> Added the knowledge tag(should've done this before).

Hint 3:

> 5.11 is not one number - it's two!

Hint 4:

> Based on Hint 3, "." stands for something. What, you ask? Just say its name out loud!

Comment: Flagged as a homework question! :-P

Comment: It seems the homework is completed. You are a good boy/girl. There is no question to answer. Provide a question to solve.

Comment: It looks like gaming keyboard keys

Comment: @MeaCulpaNay It is tagged as an enigmatic puzzle. So the teacher has given the student a piece of paper  with only what OP wrote on it and told the student to complete it. Part of the fun is figuring out what you are supposed to do

Comment: Is your homework complete?  Is there more to do to complete the homework?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your homework is to ...

> ... **go to puzzling**.

Each line of the message ...

> ... describes a letter via an element of the [periodic table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Periodic_table). The notation *p* `.` *g* `G,` *c* refers to the element in group *g* of period *p*. The index *c* tells us which letter to take from the chemical symbol.
>
>  For example, the first line `5.11G, 2` refers to silver, which is in group 5 and period 11. The answer is the second letter of the chemical symbol, Ag. Here's the full message:
>
> ```
>     5.11G, 2: Ag  G          3.15G, 1: P   P         6.13G, 2: Tl  L
>      5.6G, 2: Mo  O          6.11G, 2: Au  U          4.4G, 2: Ti  I
>     6.13G, 1: Tl  T          4.12G, 1: Zn  Z         7.12G, 2: Cn  N
>     2.16G, 1: O   O           5.4G, 1: Zr  Z         4.13G, 1: Ga  G
> ```

Comment: Got it! :) Hence the title "Just doing my homework". Curious: how many hints did you use? Would the puzzle have been too hard without them?

Comment: Ah, so it was chemistry homework. I didn't have a clue until I read the last hint, which reminded me of [this question about "Dotted words"](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/47603/what-is-a-dotted-word).

Comment: Ah, ok. And no, it wasn’t homework of any kind, I made it up :)

Answer (score 0):

I will take a stab at this although I am not sure that what I am thinking is correct...

You have apparently been assigned to find

> The names of stars, or the constellations with stars having the Magnitudes given in the Star Class range G where there are a specific number of those stars on a particular photographic plate...

The reason that 5.11 is actually two numbers is

> 5.11 may actually be the PRODUCT of two or more numbers which results in apparent magnitude

I googled this idea and found the following link:

> https://books.google.com/books?id=M1JAAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA92&lpg=PA92&dq=5.13G,+2&source=bl&ots=ekGRmdL6N9&sig=jn2Aue_5Y5eghLeATwVdVU8MPlo&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwii-eLjqfvXAhVC8IMKHYC0DjcQ6AEIVTAJ#v=onepage&q=5.13G%2C%202&f=false

Comment: Interesting idea! That's not it though. The answer is a message...